# How do I compute the max of two size_t variables

Tags: c++, gcc, max, stdvector

I have this in my code.

```
vector<unsigned int> import;
vector<unsigned int> aquired;
. . .
size_t new_size = max(import.size(),aquired.size());
```

and I get this error:

```
 error: more than one instance of
 overloaded function "max" matches the
 argument list:
             function "max(int, int)"
             function "max(unsigned int, unsigned int)"
             function "max(int, unsigned int)"
             function "max(unsigned int, int)"
             function "max(long long, long long)"
             function "max(unsigned long long, unsigned long long)"
             function "max(long long, unsigned long long)"
             function "max(unsigned long long, long long)"
             function "max(float, float)"
             function "max(double, double)"
             function "max(float, double)"
             function "max(double, float)"
             argument types are: (size_t, size_t)
```

my understanding is that `size_t` is an unsigned int.  So why is this a problem and how do I get around it.

Compiling with:

```
$gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5) 4.4.3
$nvcc --version
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2010 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Wed_Sep__8_17:12:45_PDT_2010
Cuda compilation tools, release 3.2, V0.2.1221
```

Comment: `size_t` is not necessarily an `unsigned`, but I wonder where the candidates are coming from?

Comment: I can't reproduce that on gcc 4.4.1. Can you post a complete test program?

Comment: Adding std:: to max solved the problem I think that the max was masked by another header or something.

Comment: @UncleBens citation please?  I really doubt that is true except for very old non-standards compliant implementations.  It does not make any sense for the return type of `sizeof` to be less than zero, and C99 definitely defines `size_t` as an unsigned integer type.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
#include <algorithm>

size_t val1;
size_t val2;

size_t maxValue = std::max<size_t>(val1, val2);
```

Comment: I don't think <size_t> is needed.

Answer (score 3):

size_t is not an unsigned int necessarily, it is platform dependent.  If you're compiling for 32 bit, or if you know that your vector will have size under 4 billion, you can safely cast to an unsigned int.  Some 64-bit platforms use a 64-bit size_t, but have an unsigned int as only 32-bit.
Try using this instead of your current code:

`size_t new_size = max((unsigned int)import.size(),(unsigned int)aquired.size());`

Answer (score 2):

I don't think size_t is actually unsigned int. I suspect it's its own type, not a typedef - at least in g++

Use std::max:

```
#include <algorithm>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  size_t a = 2, b=3;
  std::max(a,b);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The standard mandates that `size_t` is a typedef to an unspecified type.  But you're right that it isn't necessarily `unsigned int`.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
std::max((unsigned int)import.size(), (unsigned int)aquired.size());
```